# .Net project build successful through VSTS. Deployment on Azure cloud gets failed because of Newtonsoft.json error

Tags: azure-devops

I am building a .Net project through VSTS (Azure DevOps) using the Visual Studio build plugin. The build is successful but when I am trying to deploy it shows the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.json or its dependencies.
>   The located assembly's manifest definiton does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the screenshot you posted i guess that this error is after a successful deploy to you wepp application. You should check if newtonsoft dll is on the server(and which version). Also, if there is newtonsoft dll it might not be the same as on your local computer. Most likely you have the right version on your computer but you did not set the right parameters in app.config and package.config so the actual output package you got after building the solution does not have the right dll in it. 
I would do clean rebuild, delete obj, bin and package folder on local machine and try to build it to see if there will be this error. After that you just need to set the right dependencies